# How to make a view controller without a xib or a storyboard vc identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I wanted to know how to make a `viewcontroller` without the use of `xib` or `storyboard`. So in this case, I would be getting the `viewcontroller` as such

```
   PopupViewController* vc = [[PopupViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I know it has to do something with overriding the init method since we are not using `initWithCoder` ?

I know I have to create a view and set it as the self.view for the `PopupViewController`, but I was wondering how I could do that.

EDIT: Yes it may be much easier just to make an `xib file` or add a `view controller` to the `storyboard`, this is to understand deeply how `view controllers` work.

Comment: add frame to your viewcontroller while allocating or before adding to superview. Also do some view customization  like background color etc for your view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create the controller and the UIView programatically and not use the interface builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778856/is-there-a-way-to-create-the-controller-and-the-uiview-programatically-and-not-u)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to init the view is in `PopupViewController`'s `loadView` method. Something like:

```
- (void)loadView {
   self.view = [MyViewClass new];
}
```

Then, in `MyViewClass` `initWithFrame:` method build all subviews and set constraints to it. If you're not using constraints, override `layoutSubviews` method.